# Manejo de LinkedList

Tags: java, java-8

Estoy haciendo una clase que simule las LinkedList de java, debido a que el manejo de estas es diferente a los arrays me encuentro atascado con un par de métodos.
En el código que dejo a continuación los métodos que están un poco incompletos les puse comentarios para que se entienda que pretende hacer. A parte de la ayuda con estos métodos también necesito, en la medida de lo posible, que estén lo mejor comentados posible para poder entenderlo lo mejor posible.

**Clase LinkedList**

```java
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package ds;

import java.util.Iterator;

/**
 *
 * @author Pillado
 * @param <T>
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class LinkedList<T> implements Iterable<T>{
    //Hecho por Fran
    private ListNode<T> head;
    private int len;

    public int size() { return this.len; }

    public void add(T data) {
        ListNode<T> newNode = new ListNode<T>(data);
        newNode.setNext(this.head);
        this.head = newNode;
        ++len;
    }

    public T get(int index) {
        if(index<0 || index>=this.len) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Indice fuera de rango: " + index);
        if(index==0) return head.getData(); // si queremos el primero de la lista
        ListNode<T> node = head; // si no, empezamos por el primero...
        while(index-->0) node = node.getNext(); // saltamos de nodo en nodo tantas veces como index
        return node.getData();
    }

    //Hecho por Julio
    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator(){
        return new Iterator(){
            @SuppressWarnings("FieldMayBeFinal")
            private int p = 0;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return (p < len);
            }

            @Override
            public Object next() {
                return null;
                //return data[p++];//modificar
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * Vacía el LinkedList
     */
    public void clear(){
        for (int i = 0; i < this.len; i++) {
            this.remove(i);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Inserta el dato en la posición indicada
     * @param index indice del array
     * @param data dato a almacenar
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException indice fuera de rango
     */
    public void add(int index, T data){
        if(index<0 || index>=this.len) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Indice fuera de rango: " + index);
        this.len++;
    }

    /**
     * Modifica el valor en la posición indicada con el nuevo dato
     * @param index indice del array
     * @param data dato a almacenar
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException indice fuera de rango
     */
    public void set(int index, T data){
        if(index<0 || index>=this.len) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Indice fuera de rango: " + index);
    }

    /**
     * Devuelve el dato de la posición indicada y la elimina del array
     * @param index indice a eliminar
     * @return dato que se ha eliminado del array
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException indice fuera de rango
     */
    public T remove(int index){
        if(index<0 || index>=this.len) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Indice fuera de rango: " + index);
        T data = null;
        this.len--;
        return data;
    }

    /**
     * Elimina el dato del array. Devuelve un valor indicando si la operación tuvo éxito o no
     * @param data dato a eliminar
     * @return Booleano, true si se ha eliminado
     */
    public boolean delete(T data){
        int index = indexOf(data);
        if (index != -1) { remove(index); }

        return (index != -1);
    }

    /**
     * Devuelve la posición en la que se encuentra dato indicado
     * @param data dato a buscar en el array
     * @return Indice donde esta la cadena, -1 si no encuentra
     */
    public int indexOf(T data){
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Clase ListNode

```java
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package ds;

/**
 *
 * @author Pillado
 * @param <T>
 */
public class ListNode<T> {
    private T data;
    private ListNode next;

    ListNode(T data) { this.data = (T) data; }

    T getData() { return this.data; }

    ListNode getNext() { return this.next; }

    void setNext(ListNode<T> nextNode) { this.next = nextNode; }
}
```

Soy consciente que de esta vez estoy pidiendo demasiado con este problema pero estoy bastante atascado con el. Gracias por la ayuda.

**-- MODIFICACÍON --**

El problema que tengo trata de manejar los nodos. Cuando hay que añadir un nodo hay que modificar las correspondientes referencias a los nodos, cuando se trata de eliminar un nodo también hay que modificar las referencias y es esto que aun no se como hacerlo.
Los métodos en cuestión están en la clase LinkedList y son los siguientes:

```java
public void add(int index, T data){}
public void set(int index, T data){}
public T remove(int index)
```

También hay un iterator en el que no se muy bien como sobrescribir el método next.

**-- MODIFICACIÓN --**
Dejo unas imágenes que muestran los resultados después de usa el método set y add
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**-- MODIFICACIÓN --**
A continuacion dejo tres capturas de pantalla de como tengo implementado los metodos set y add
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema lo tengo en la clase LinkedList, la clase ListNode esta bien tal y como esta, o eso creo, simplemente la puse por que en la clase LinkedList hago referencia a esta

Comment: No entiendo, ¿qué problemas tienen esos métodos? Te recomiendo editar la pregunta y agregar en detalle **cual es el problema.**

Comment: @MrDave1999 Acabo de hacer una pequeña modificacion, espero que ahora entiendas cuales son los problemas que tengo

Comment: Nunca hagas una pregunta con muchas subpreguntas, porque harás que la respuesta sea muy larga y de paso, tendrás poca ayuda. Para la próxima, por cada duda que tengas, haz una pregunta por separado. Así es más fácil de responder.

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta con el tema del `iterator`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## **Método 1**

```java
public void add(int index, T data)
```

**Deberemos seguir el siguiente algoritmo:**

**1.-** Crearemos un nuevo nodo donde guardaremos el objeto al que apunte el parámetro `data`.

**2.-** Recorremos la lista enlazada hasta encontrar el nodo que esté en la posición dada.

**3.-** Enlazamos el campo siguiente del nuevo nodo con el nodo al que apunte la variable auxiliar.

**4.-** Si la posición es diferente a `0`, es porque la variable auxiliar apunta a un nodo intermedio o al último. Si se cumple esta condición, debemos enlazar el nodo anterior con el nuevo nodo.

**5.-** Si el **paso 4** no se cumple, es porque la variable auxiliar apunta al primer nodo, por lo tanto, debemos actualizar la referencia `head`, ya que el nuevo nodo será el **primer nodo**.

**6.-** Incrementamos la variable `len`.

**Código en Java:**

```java
public void add(int index, T data)
{
    if(index < 0 || index >= len) 
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Indice fuera de rango: " + index);
    
    int i = 0;
    ListNode<T> aux = head;
    /* En esta variable almacenamos el nodo anterior */
    ListNode<T> prev = null;
    /* En esta variable almacenamos el nuevo nodo junto con el dato */
    ListNode<T> newNode = new ListNode<T>(data);
    while(true)
    {
        if(i++ == index)
        {
            /* Enlazamos el nuevo nodo con el nodo al que apunte aux */
            newNode.setNext(aux);
            /* Si no coincide con el primer nodo */
            if(prev != null)
                /* Enlazamos el nodo anterior con el nuevo */
                prev.setNext(newNode);
            else /* De lo contrario */
                /* Actualizamos la referencia "head" */
                head = newNode;
            len++;
            break;
        }
        prev = aux;
        aux = aux.getNext();
    }
}
```

**Comprobación:**

Imaginemos que la lista enlazada tiene los siguientes elementos:

```java
Position:   5  4   3  2  1  0
LinkedList: 1, 5, 10, 0, 5, 7 <-- aux
                            |
                           head
```

Ahora usaremos nuestro algoritmo para insertar el número `25` en la posición `2`.

**1.-** Recorremos la lista hasta encontrar el nodo con la posición dada:

```java
Position:   5  4   3  2  1  0
LinkedList: 1, 5, 10, 0, 5, 7
                      |     |
                     aux   head
```

**2.-** Enlazamos el nuevo nodo con el que apunte la referencia `aux`:

```java
Position:   6  5   4  3  2  
LinkedList: 1, 5, 10, 0, 20
                      |     
                     aux
```

Posteriormente enlazamos el nodo anterior (el que estaba antes del nodo al que apuntaba `aux`) con el nuevo nodo:

```java
Position:   6  5   4  3  2   1  0
LinkedList: 1, 5, 10, 0, 20, 5, 7
                      |         |
                     aux       head
```

¡Listo! Hemos insertado el número `20` en la posición `2`.

**¿Qué pasaría si insertamos el número `25` en la posición `0`?**

*Seguimos los pasos:*

**1.-** Recorremos la lista hasta encontrar el nodo con la posición dada:

```java
Position:   6  5   4  3  2   1  0
LinkedList: 1, 5, 10, 0, 20, 5, 7  <-- aux; prev = null
                                |
                               head
```

**2.-** Enlazamos el nuevo nodo con el que apunte la referencia `aux` y actualizamos la referencia `head`:

```java
Position:   7  6   5  4  3   2  1  0 
LinkedList: 1, 5, 10, 0, 20, 5, 7, 25 ; prev = null
                                |  |
                               aux head
```

El último paso se cancela porque no hay un nodo anterior.

## **Método 2**

```java
public void set(int index, T data)
```

La implementación de este método es sencillo, por esa razón no incluiré una comprobación ni algoritmo.

**Código en Java:**

```java
public void set(int index, T data)
{
    if(index <0 || index >= len) 
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Indice fuera de rango: " + index);
    
    int i = 0;
    ListNode<T> aux = head;
    while(true)
    {
        if(i++ == index)
        {
            /* Reemplazamos el anterior objeto por el nuevo */
            aux.setData(data);
            break;
        }
        aux = aux.getNext();
    }
    
}
```

**Nota:** El método `setData` debe estar definido en la clase genérica `ListNode`.

## **Método 3**

```java
public T remove(int index)
```

**Su algoritmo es:**

**1.-** Recorremos la lista hasta encontrar el nodo con la posición dada.

**2.-** Verificamos si la variable auxiliar coincide con el primer nodo, si se cumple la condición, debemos actualizar la referencia `head`, ya que apuntará al nodo al que apunte el campo siguiente del nodo al que apunte `aux`.

**3.-** Si la variable `aux` coincide con el último nodo, debemos asignar un `null` al campo siguiente del anterior nodo. De esto depende que la lista enlazada tenga un fin.

**4.-** Si la variable `aux` coincide con un nodo intermedio, debemos enlazar el campo siguiente del anterior nodo con el nodo al que apunte el campo siguiente del nodo al que apunte `aux`.

**Código en Java:**

```java
public T remove(int index)
{
    if(index <0 || index >= len) 
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Indice fuera de rango: " + index);
    
    T data;
    int i = 0;
    ListNode<T> aux = head;
    ListNode<T> prev = null;
    while(true)
    {
        if(i++ == index)
        {
            /* Si coincide con el primer nodo */
            if(aux == head)
                head = aux.getNext();
            /* Si coincide con el último nodo */
            else if(len-1 == i)
                prev.setNext(null);
            /* Si coincide con un nodo intermedio */
            else
                prev.setNext(aux.getNext());
            
            data = aux.getData();
            len--;
            break;
        }
        prev = aux;
        aux = aux.getNext();
    }
    return data;
}
```

> > También hay un iterator en el que no se muy bien como sobrescribir el método next.

Para poder recorrer la lista enlazada necesitas de una referencia auxiliar. Por esa razón debemos agregarla como un atributo en la clase `LinkedList`:

```java
public class LinkedList<T> implements Iterable<T>
{
    private ListNode<T> head;
    /* Atributo auxiliar */
    private ListNode<T> auxLK;
    private int len;
    //more code ...
    //...
}
```

Posteriormente, debemos asignar el contenido al que apunte `head` en `auxLK`. Esta asignación se la hará en el método `iterator()`.

En el método `hasNext()` solo debemos agregar una condición en la cual nos indica si la variable auxiliar llegó a `null` (nos indica el fin de la lista enlazada) y en el método `next()` se debe retornar el objeto de tipo `T`, por esa razón hice que la clase anónima sea genérica.

**Ejemplo:**

```java
public class LinkedList<T> implements Iterable<T>
{
    private ListNode<T> head;
    /* Atributo auxiliar */
    private ListNode<T> auxLK;
    private int len;
    
    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator()
    {
        /* Asignamos la dirección del primer nodo en "auxLK" */
        auxLK = head;
        /* clase anonima generica */
        return new Iterator<T>(){
            @SuppressWarnings("FieldMayBeFinal")

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() 
            {
                /* Si auxLK no apunta a null, es porque hay elementos */
                return auxLK != null;
            }

            @Override
            public T next() 
            {
                /* Guardamos la dirección base del nodo al que apunte auxLK en aux2 */
                ListNode<T> aux2 = auxLK;
                /* Actualizamos la referencia "auxLK" */
                auxLK = auxLK.getNext();
                /* Retornamos el objeto de tipo T */
                return aux2.getData();
            }
        };
    }
    
    
    //more code ...
    //...
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, esta muy bien explica. Quiero avisarte que los métodos `public void add(int index, T data)` y `public void set(int index, T data)` no funcionan bien, en un main tengo una instancia de linkedlist con 3 elementos [4, -3, 5], usando el método `public void add(1, 10)` tendría que salir lo siguiente: [4, 10, -3, 5] sin embargo la salida que me da es la siguiente: [4, 10, 4, 10, 4]. Con el método set da igual el indice que le pase solo modifica el primer valor. Ahora mismo estoy intentando corregir esto.

Comment: En el iterator hay una cosa que no entiendo, en el método next para que se usa aux2, no se podria hacer directamente con auxLK. Con respecto al resto del iterator todo bien.

Comment: @JPillado No es que esté mal el método `add`. Simplemente la forma como implementaste este LinkedList, tiene la forma de una pila, por lo tanto al imprimir los datos, será al revés. Cuando propuse la solución, me fije en la forma como implementaste este método: `public void add(T data)` y ahí se ve claro, que tiene la forma de una **pila**. Entonces, el método `add` que propuse, funciona expresamente con esa implementación. Por ejemplo, si los elementos de la lista son: [4, -3, 5], al imprimirlo, debería salir: [5, -3, 4] porque `head` apunta al nodo donde está el elemento `5`.

Comment: @JPillado Entonces si quisiéramos agregar el número `10` en la posición `1`, quedaría así la lista: [4, -3, 10, 5], al imprimirlo por pantalla, debería de salir: [5, 10, -3, 4]. La lógica del método la veo bien y expresamente para la lista enlazada que implementaste. Con respecto al método `set`, ¿cómo lo estás usando? No veo ningún error en el método que propuse. Por último, es necesario usar la variable `aux2` porque necesitamos tener guardado el anterior nodo, si retornas directamente con `auxLK`, te dará el elemento siguiente y no el anterior.

Comment: Acabo de modificar la pregunta para dejar dos capturas de pantalla en donde puedes puedes ver el main que tengo y el resultado después de ejecutarlo. Se que tal y como lo tengo el primer dato en almacenar sera el ultimo en mostrarse cuando dije [4, -3, 5] hacia mencion a la salida por consolo despues de ejecutar el programa. En vez de dar [4, 10, -3, 5] sin embargo el resultado es  [4, 10, 4, 10, 4], borrando los datos [-3, 5] y en su lugar ponen los datos [4, 10]

Comment: Si necesitas otras capturas de pantalla o lo que necesites para entender mejor este problema avisa, como dato diré que el ide que estoy usando es el netbeans.

Comment: @JPillado Sería bueno que agregues el código de como lo has implementado o lo has agregado **literalmente** como lo puse sin ninguna modificación? Ya mismo hago la prueba del código. Puesto estas soluciones la hice ayer por la noche y no tuve tiempo para revisar si funcionaba

Comment: Acabo de dejar unas capturas de pantalla de como tengo implementado los metodos set y add, estan tal y como estan en tu respuesta. El resto del codigo es el que ya deje junto con el de tu respuesta.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108094/discussion-between-mrdave1999-and-jpillado).